# forEach displays undefined between my array lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am a beginner in Javascript.

I am trying to create an array with a list of contacts, then display all the contacts with "forEach".
My issue is that I get "undefined" between my contacts.
My code :

```
var Person = {
   init : function (name, firstname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstname = firstname;
   },

    myContact : function() {
       console.log('Name : ' + this.name + ', Fistname : ' + this.firstname);
   }

};

var carole = Object.create(Person);
carole.init('Lévisse', 'Carole');

var melodie = Object.create(Person);
melodie.init('Nelsonne', 'Mélodie');

var contacts = [carole, melodie];

console.log('All your contacts :');

contacts.forEach(function(indiv) {
    console.log(indiv.myContact());
});
```

The result is :

*All you contacts :

Nom : Lévisse, Prénom : Carole

undefined

Nom : Nelsonne, Prénom : Mélodie

undefined*

What is wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doubling the `console.log()`.

Here, you're basically doing `console.log(function(){console.log(...)})`.

The `function` doesn't have a `return` statement so it returns : `undefined`.

To fix that, remove a `console.log()`:

```js
var Person = {
  init: function(name, firstname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstname = firstname;
  },

  myContact: function() {
    console.log('Name : ' + this.name + ', Fistname : ' + this.firstname);
  }

};

var carole = Object.create(Person);
carole.init('Lévisse', 'Carole');

var melodie = Object.create(Person);
melodie.init('Nelsonne', 'Mélodie');

var contacts = [carole, melodie];

console.log('All your contacts :');

contacts.forEach(function(indiv) {
  indiv.myContact(); //Removed a console.log() here
});
```

Comment: @Zenoo As per naming of function `myContact `, `console.log` from `myContact` function should be remove. instead of from `forEach`